# Add character to attribute in VueJs Templating

Tags: vue.js

So let say I have a class `label-dog`.

Let say I want to declare the class in a VueJs element like.

`<img :class="type" >`

With class of animal being something like

`data: { type: dog }`

How do I add the "label-" part to the class? Is there a syntax for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
<img :class="'label-' + type" >
```

You can also define a computed property to 'build' your class:

```
computed: {
  fullClass() {
    return 'label-'+ this.type;
  }
},
```